# porting pulse audio on Android

Tags: android, pulseaudio

I am planning to port pulse audio on android. I have compiled it on ubuntu after removing the optional parts (like X dependency, oss support etc) and I am able to remote my sound to a network server (running windows-7). Now I want to port this to android. Any idea on how to start would be appreciated or a link to some page which is doing some thing similar that can get me started with a basic Makefile infrastructure.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share what you've got so far? I don't have a clue how to port something like this, but i'd like to have a look at your work. I'm really interested in this, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use Maven to build the app. It handle's some dependency things. If you want an example you can look at something that I have been working on.

https://github.com/kopysoft/Chronos/blob/development/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

[Arun Raghavan](http://arunraghavan.net/) spend some time at [Collabora](http://www.collabora.com/projects/pulseaudio) porting and testing [PulseAudio for Android](http://arunraghavan.net/2012/01/pulseaudio-vs-audioflinger-fight/). He is currently pushing the needed patches to the various upstream projects.